# Flex - Difference between creationComplete and ApplicationComplete event?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe, event-handling

Folks,

I didn't get the difference between those two event.

What is the difference between them ?
Explanation with e.g will always be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'll add one correction here.  creationComplete and applicationComplete are events; not event handlers.  A handler is a method that is executed when the event is dispatched.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ee6.html

Each component dispatches a creationComplete message during application startup - if it is meant to be created at startup.  Otherwise each component will dispatch the message whenever it is actually created.

From the documentation link above:

> After all components are created and
>   drawn, the Application object
>   dispatches an applicationComplete
>   event. This is the last event
>   dispatched during an application
>   startup.

*Edited to reflect other times when creationComplete events get dispatched, besides just the context of application startup.

Comment: Both answers provided the same flow diagram. +1

Comment: I have to downvote this one for being inaccurate.  creationComplete is dispatched as part of the component's creation lifecycle; which may not be part of Application startup.  There are plenty of use cases which create components after the applicaiton's startup has been created.  ViewStacks with the default creationPolicy is one such use case.

Answer (score 2):

See this [link with](http://www.wietseveenstra.nl/blog/2007/02/understanding-the-flex-application-startup-event-order/) the full explanation. In addition, `creationComplete` is dispatched by every Flex component but `applicationComplete` dispatched only one time by `Application` itself.

Comment: Both answers provided the same flow diagram. +1

Answer (score 1):

Both the Creationcomplete and application complete is part of the flex application life cycle.  For more information and examples you can go to the following link:

http://technobytz.com/flex-preinitialize.html

Answer (score 0):

Another important difference is your application doesn't have a reference to the stage until the applicationComplete is dispatched